# Каково происхождение фразеологизма «прописные истины»?

Tags: этимология, фразеология, значение-слов

Толковый словарь Ожегова:

> Прописная истина — всем известная, тривиальная мысль.

Откуда пошло называть истины прописными?

Может быть, это изначально были истины, которые были где-то прописаны, например, в каком-то священном писании?

Или, может, это выражение происходит от слова «пропись»?

В Малом академическом словаре под редакцией Евгеньевой есть такое переносное определение прописи:

> 2. перен. Общеизвестная, избитая мысль, сентенция.
>    *Как это отзывается **прописью** и какая это правда, вечная и глубокая, в своей избитости.*
>    Боборыкин, Поумнел.
>    *Автор заводит беседу, лишенную всяких
>    морализирующих нажимов и нудных **прописей**.*
>    Михалков, Беседа, в которой
>    интересно участвовать.

Но если это переносное значение, то от какого прямого значения оно образовалось?

В этом же словаре первое значение:

> **про́пись**, -и, ж. 1. Учебное печатное пособие для обучения письму,
> состоящее из образцов принятого в общеобразовательной школе написания
> букв, а также само написание букв по этому образцу... || Письмо от
> руки среди печатного текста.

Но перенос названия «пропись» со школьной прописи на общеизвестную мысль не совсем понятен, потому что в школьных прописях есть образцы написания букв, а не общеизвестные мысли или какие-то истины.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот фразеологизм возник благодаря тому, что старые прописи учили не только красивому почерку, но и уму-разуму в широком смысле. Посмотреть, как это выглядело, можно, например, здесь: https://vivaldi.nlr.ru/bx000007544/view/?#page=17

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Получается, они использовали для тренировки чистописания мудрые высказывания. Похожие мудрости сейчас любят публиковать в социальных сетях: чьи то высказывания, цитаты откуда-то и т. п. Красивые прописи. И это 1844 год. Они были напечатаны, когда не существовало компьютеров. Как точно непечатно, как единообразно написаны буквы. А ведь это ручная работа, никаких компьютерных программ не существовало.